# MySQL count with case return wrong count

Tags: mysql, case

I have following problem:

I have mysql table with:

```
continent,  
country,  
city,  
zip,  
street,  
status (int),  
reason (varchar, can be empty or some text),  
... (some other columns, not required for query)
```

I want to count occurence of each status by *country,city,zip,street* but with mapping of status int to text:

```
SELECT country,city,zip,street, 
   CASE WHEN (status = '2' AND reason <> '') THEN "BLOCKED" 
        WHEN (status = '2' AND reason='') THEN "DISPUTED"  
        WHEN status = '3' THEN 'EXPIRED' 
        WHEN status = '1' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
        END as status, 
    count(*) AS count
FROM people
where continent='Europe'
GROUP BY country,city,zip,street,status
```

I think that problem is in GROUP BY but not sure - it don't return correct data.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89792/1/0)
(Check Paris/Street2 - it shows 3 DISPUTED and should show 1 BLOCKED and 2 DISPUTED)

Thanks for opinions.

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide examples of how it is not correct?  Or, even better, set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: try count(status) instead of count(*)

Comment: I commend your effort.  But I concern about all that logic in a status+reason.  Can you create a second ENUM table with status(es) and do a join.  Then get count(*) with a simplier query?

Comment: I tried to add sqlfiddle, but still in progres... COUNT(STATUS) is not helping. Regarding add new table... maybe it is possible, but this is asap query :) Also I find that problem is in "reason <> ''" - this just don't work, even in plain query... can it be problem?

Comment: You didn't show the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think EngineerCoder *meant to write*:

```
select country,city,zip,street, status, count(*) 
from
(
SELECT country,city,zip,street, 
   CASE WHEN (status = '2' AND reason <> '') THEN "BLOCKED" 
        WHEN (status = '2' AND reason='') THEN "DISPUTED"  
        WHEN status = '3' THEN 'EXPIRED' 
        WHEN status = '1' THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' 
   END as status, 
FROM people
where continent='Europe'
) AS ilv
GROUP BY country,city,zip,street,status
```